# VBA: Extracting text and attachments from Outlook to Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, outlook

I have a question about extracting data from an Outlook message to an Excel spreadsheet. Usually, I'm able to extract the body of a message and the attachments associated with said message, but I do not know how to do that in order. This is what the message looks like:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/rwklyt.jpg

What I need to do is put the date in the first cell of a row, followed by the text "Message[i]", and then open the XML file associated with that date and put the information of that XML file in the next cell of the same row.

Like I said, I believe I would be able to get text and the attachments, but I do not know how to associate the XML files with the dates, knowing that I don't know in advance the number of files per date.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN.

There are three main ways of working with item bodies:

1. Body - a raw text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these way in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article.

Also you may find the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.